# Coordinate API OAuth2 authentication with refresh token

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, oauth-2.0, coordinate

I am looking for a sample code to authenticate Coordinate API using OAuth2 with an existing refresh token. I am looking for something similar in the thread [Google Coordinate OAuth2 with Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177262/google-coordinate-oath2-with-service-account). I have tried that code snippet but I faced some issue due to the dll conflict. And from the nuget library it seems like the `Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2` is deprecated and we should use `Google.Apis.Auth`instead.

So If somebody can provide a sample code which will work with `Google.Apis.Auth` that would be great.

Please help.

Comment: Any hope from anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find a solution by trying different combination. Adding the sample code and I think it will help somebody looking for a similar solution.

```
        using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
        using Google.Apis.Coordinate.v1;
        using Google.Apis.Coordinate.v1.Data;
        using Google.Apis.Services;
        using Google.Apis.Util.Store;


        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            new[] { CoordinateService.Scope.Coordinate },
            "user", CancellationToken.None,new FileDataStore(folder));
        }

        var service = new CoordinateService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "appname",
        });

        var list = await service.Location.List("teamid", "team@mailid.com", 2000).ExecuteAsync();
```

Hope this will help.

Thanks,
MG